# If a series converges, then the following sequence converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\sum_nx_n$ converges to $A$. Then how do I show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}+...+x_{n+k}=0?$$

First I need to show that this sequence converges, right? If I can show that the rest is easy: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=0}x_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n+k}_{i=0}x_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum^n_{i=0}x_i+\sum^{n+k}_{n+1}x_i\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=0}x_i+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n+k}_{n+1}x_i=A+\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n+k}_{n+1}x_i=A$$. Therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n+k}_{n+1}x_i=0$.

Comment: This is called "Cauchy's Convergence Criterion"

Comment: If $k$ is fixed, Cauchy's convergence test is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+k} x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n+k} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i \to A- A = 0,\quad n\to\infty$$
since both 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+k} x_i \quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$$
converges to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is fixed:

Note that $x_{n+1} \to 0$. This is because a necessary condition for the convergence of a series is that the general term converges to zero.

Similarly, $x_{n+2} \to 0, \ldots, x_{n+k} \to 0$.

By adding the $k$ sequences together we get $x_{n+1} + \ldots + x_{n+k} \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Use cauchy's series criterion on the partial sums! :)

Comment: Oh, thanks! It worked!

Comment: If $k$ is fixed, Cauchy's convergence test is not needed.